# Pyinstaller exe failed to load/predict pickle.dat due to "No module named 'xgboost'".[In <env> spyder/python3.7 console import xgb found/ is working]

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, xgboost

I have created a new environment with the necessary conda imports module (including xgboost) working in console/spyder5 mode (python3.7).
Folder structure as follows
V: Current_folder

- main.py
- ref_files (with image/pickle.data/joblib.dat for prediction call function to main.py)

### While generating pyinstaller exe,the below details are added in spec file [for ref_files]

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None

```
added_files = [("Ref_files", "Ref_files")]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['V:\\Current_folder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main.py',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Only pickle.dat file(from xgboost) load for main.py is not executing due to "xgbboost modulue not found."
Tried with

```
1.hidden_files = [('xgboost')]
2.hidden_files = [('env/xgboost_lib_path')]
```

... dll/VERSION file path also provided.
Could you please suggest is there any workout or fix on xgboost module dll/exe ??

Comment: Windows 10, Python3.7,xgboost.__version__(1.4.0 conda install)

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally I have solved the issue of XGBoost module 

1.  copying xgboost module file from anaconda/ env installation folder to 
     main_script.py folder
     [C:\Anaconda3\envs\new\Library\mingw-w64\bin] : 
     “VERSION” & “xgboost.dll”
               
2.  Include binary file in spec file:   

    binaries=[('xgboost.dll','Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\'), ('VERSION', 'xgboost\\')],
             
 
3.  Included “import xgboost.sklearn” in main_scipt.py

Now it is working fine. Pyinstaller single.exe 

Similary "sklearn.ensemble.forest module not found" issue is resolved by incorporating 
 the below imports module in main script.py as below:

import sklearn
import sklearn.utils._cython_blas
import sklearn.ensemble._forest
import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
import sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree
import sklearn.tree
import sklearn.tree._utils
```